# Matching size of controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, size, windows-phone-8.1

This is recurring problem I'm going into. How to match size of elements in WPF? Let's look at the following scenario:

```
<Grid>
    <Popup>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="btn1" />
            <Button x:Name="btn2" />
            <Button x:Name="btn3" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
    <Border x:Name="border1">
        Ala ma kota
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Now I'd like the `btn1`, `btn2` and `btn3` to be **at least as wide** as `border1`; contents of border changes dynamically, so no measuring and hardcoding is acceptable.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you try something like `<Popup ... Width="{Binding ElementName=border1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>`?

Comment: @dkozl Changes in ActualWidth for some unknown reason aren't reported by WPF.

Comment: `ActualWidth` is a `DependencyProperty` and as such it reports changes. Maybe when `border1` is stretched it simply does not change. I've tested it and it worked in my WPF app

Comment: I've tested it on Windows Phone - I set a fake converter and set a breakpoint inside: the breakpoint was never hit.

Comment: Did you try setting `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` or `border1`? If item is stretched `ActualWidth` does not change

Answer (score 0):

Bind the buttons' Width property to the Border's Width property.

Something like:

```
<Button x:Name="btn1" Width="{Binding ElementName=border1, Path=Width}" />
```

Comment: I was just writing something like that. I think he should be binding Button's MinWidth to Border's ActualWidth though.

Comment: @ScottNimrod First: then they will be *exactly* as wide, not *at least* as wide as border1. Secondly: if control is being layouted by - for instance - HorizontalAlignment or VerticalAlignment, Width may be as well 0 or NaN. Welcome to WPF world.

Comment: @yasen Tried. Doesn't work for some reason. I've debugged it with a fake converter and it seems, that WPF doesn't report changes on ActualWidth, so if you bind to it, value will be set only once (mostly probably to 0).

Comment: There's an ActualWidth property as well.

Comment: WPF or Windows Phone Silverlight or Windows Phone Runtime? They are all slightly different, and the code snippet isn't valid for any of them. The Border will also fill its container and not its contents and so may not be what you actually expect. You can set its Border and BorderThickness properties to see what it actually covers.

That said, the general answer will be the same. There isn't a direct binding for a minimum width so you'll have to implement that in code. Try binding the image's Width to the Border with an IValueConverter to convert the Border (or its contents) to a minimum size.